# How to compile TypeScript file from Ant without Node?

Tags: java, node.js, maven, ant, rhino

I'm looking for a way to compile my TypeScript files from Ant, but I don't have node and can't use it on the production server for some reasons.

I found some solution using `maven`, but not with Ant. I basically need to run `Rhino` instead of Node.

Also, I'm wondering how works the node packages with Rhino, does Rhino have its own package manager or is it possible to use the Node modules?